# scanf() error handling inside a while loop?

Tags: c

I'm new to the C programming language and I'm stumped on how I should catch a scanf() error using scanf() as a condition in a while loop.

The code is something like:

```
while (scanf("%d", &number == 1) && other_condition)
{
   ...
}
```

How could I tell when a integer was not entered so I could print out a relevant error message?

Comment: Are you asking how to distinguish the cases "loop terminated because `scanf()` failed" and "loop terminated because `other_condition` was false?"

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for scanf, particularly its return value. Also, your code above is mis-parenthesized.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to determine if the `scanf()` failed as opposed to the other condition.  The way many C developers approach this is to store the result in a variable.  Thankfully, since assignment evaluates to a value, we can actually do this as part of the loop.

```
int scanf_result;

/* ... */

// We do the assignment inline...
//                    |            then test the result
//                    v                       v
while (((scanf_result = scanf("%d", &number)) == 1) && other_condition) {
    /* Loop body */
}

if (scanf_result != 1) {
    /* The loop terminated because scanf() failed. */
} else {
    /* The loop terminated for some other reason. */
}
```

Comment: @chux "On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file."

Comment: @chux `EOF` is returned for input failure, `0` is returned for matching failure.

Comment: I forgot to account for the `EOF` possibility, but it can also return zero if the match fails because there is input, but it's not a number. The answer has been updated.

Comment: @chux It could be zero if the user enters "foobar" -- which isn't an EOF condition, but it's also not numeric.

Comment: @chux Read the text I quoted ... it says how quite explicitly.

Comment: *It could be zero if the user enters "foobar"* -- It will also return 0 if the user enters EOF (or if the end of an actual file is encountered). It will return EOF if the end of file had been reached (or an error had occurred) before scanf was even called.

Comment: I stand well corrected.  I was confusing with the case of `sscanf(" ", "%s", some_char_star)` that returns `EOF` or `1`.

Comment: *Doesn't scanf("%d", &number) return EOF if no conversions occurred?* -- No, not normally ...

Comment: @Jim `sscanf(" ", "%d", &i)` will return `EOF`, but not `sscanf("foobar", "%d", &i)` as mentioned.

Comment: @chux No it won't. Read the documentation that I cited. From the linux manual (and other sources agree): "The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error. "

Comment: @Jim My gcc must be non-compliant then.  `printf("%d\n", sscanf(" ", "%d", &i));` --> -1 and `printf("%d\n", sscanf("foobar", "%d", &i));` --> 0

Comment: @chux Sorry, you're correct, that returns EOF ... but because the leading whitespace is skipped before sscanf even attempts a conversion. Again, as I noted several times, EOF is only returned if end-of-file (or error) occurred *before the conversion was attempted*. A match failure returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using this logic, you can't tell. You will only know that either scanf failed, or the other condition failed.

If the other condition has no side-effect and can be executed before the scanf without changing the program's behaviour you could write:

```
while ( other_condition && 1 == scanf("%d", &number) )
{
    // ...
}

if ( other_condition )
    { /* failed due to other_condition */ }
else
    { /* failed due to scanf or break */ }
```

Alternatively you could explicitly store each scanf result:

```
int result = 0;

while ( 1 == (result = scanf("%d", &number)) && other_condition ) 
{
     // ...
}

if ( 1 == result )
    { /* failed due to other_condition or break */ }
else
    { /* failed due to scanf */ }
```

NB. I use the Yoda Condition as I prefer that style in this scenario, but you don't have to.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the condition of the loop should be the input:

```
scanf("%d",number);
while(number==1 && other)
```

Comment: I see, seems like i skipped the last line of the question, sorry

Comment: Well, "scanf() error" appears both in the title and in the first sentence.